# How to use oAuth to sign in using google acount?

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am working on android platform and I want to use oAuth to sign in using google account.But I am new with oAuth,couldn't signed in.

---

Error-sign in using another account 
Please help. 
Explain steps in detail how to use oAuth to sign-in using google+ account.

Comment: Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: @Rian Sir, I have implementesd that applicaiton using the documentation provided by the google and android hive code. Its showing the login button 
but showing the error cannot sign in with this account.

Comment: You have to provide more information if you want us to help you. Show the exact error you are getting and the relevant code.

Comment: @Rian Can you give me your mail id so that i can send you the snapshot of it.

Comment: This is not how Stack Overflow works. Please read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Rian I have followed these steps to intgrate rthe google oAuth 
https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android but actually whats happening is that when we clicking the button for signing up it shows the error "Error Signing with the specific account .Choose different account "